# Glide/Gaelyk/Groovy: Error deploying to Google App Engine: Can’t enter oauth2 token

Tags: google-app-engine, groovy, gaelyk, groovy-glide

As part of the deployment process of a Glide project (http://glide-gae.appspot.com/docs/intro step 3 of 2nd section) you need to authenticate using oauth2. My browser popped up with the token as expected but the process didn’t wait for me to copy the code in, it just carried on with the following error...

```
22:30:12.713 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] Daemon is busy, sleeping until state changes.
22:30:12.733 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient] About to start relaying all logs to the client via the connection.
22:30:12.734 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient] The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 12557). The daemon log file: /.gradle/daemon/1.8/daemon-12557.out.log
22:30:12.739 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 14: received class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput
22:30:12.740 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultDaemonConnection] Received IO message from client: CloseInput[id=069864b2-2948-4a9d-abea-0705274136a1.2]
22:30:12.741 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput] Closing daemon's stdin at end of input.
22:30:12.742 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput] The daemon will no longer process any standard input.
22:30:12.747 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] Executing build with daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=3901cff0-8d50-41b6-9459-e31f7b78f1e3,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=.gradle/daemon,pid=12557,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8]
Please enter code: Encountered a problem: No line found
Please see the logs [/var/folders/c8/vx2jf50j68x1z3_pysy6kxjm0000gp/T/appcfg2389447403250678065.log] for further information.
Daemon vm is shutting down... The daemon has exited normally or was terminated in response to a user interrupt.
----- End of the daemon log -----
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle       distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip'.
```

What can I do to be able to deploy my application? How can I force the process to wait for me to enter the code?

Answer (score 3):

If that's (`glide deploy`) not working for you, the easiest option is to export the app as a standard `gradle` project and then execute the `gaeUpdate` task.

`glide -a somedir/yourapp -o where/you/want/to/export/app export`

Note that the `export` is command at the end, `-o` tell the location where it should be exported.

Then from the exported project run: `gradle gaeUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to manually set your credentials in the GAE build.gradle file.

Update the following file:

/glide/install/generated/app-name/build.gradle

```
appcfg {

  email = ‘email-address'     
  password = ‘password'

  app {
     id = ‘app-id'
  }
}
```

This means that the values from the __glide.groovy file are ignored, but at least you can get the application deployed

Comment: manually setting credentials in generated app is not a good idea 1.  because storing password as text and 2. as this file will get overwritten by glide's continuous sync. You may wish to discuss at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/glide-groovy becuase SO is not good place to discuss.