# Glide/Gaelyk/Groovy: Error deploying to Google App Engine: Missing web.xml (No such file or directory)

Tags: google-app-engine, groovy, gaelyk, groovy-glide

The Glide Google App Engine (https://github.com/kdabir/glide) project looks like a great way to get simple Groovy scripts hosted and running on the web.

However, after following the instructions on http://glide-gae.appspot.com/docs/intro I get errors when trying to deploy to the GAE server.

I set the __glide.groovy up as in the ‘2 minutes to deploy’. However as soon as I run "glide deploy" I get the following error…

```
      ___  _  _     _
     / __|| |(_) __| | ___
    | (_ || || |/ _` |/ -_)
     \___||_||_|\__,_|\___|

     version : 0.3-SNAPSHOT
     build   : 28.01.14 22:51:08

 [sync] Copying 4 files to /software/glide/install/generated/app-name

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:/software/glide/install/generated/app-name/app/WEB-INF/web.xml 
(No such file or directory)
```

Software Versions Used:

```
Glide:
version : 0.3-SNAPSHOT
build   : 17.01.14 17:02:02

java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Groovy Version: 2.2.1 JVM: 1.7.0_51 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X

Gradle 1.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_51 (Oracle Corporation 24.51-b03)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.9.1 x86_64
```

What can I change to deploy this app?

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the /software/glide/install/generated directory there are two subdirectories. app-name_0 which was generated by running the glide command in the first part of the docs ( http://glide-gae.appspot.com/docs/intro) and the directory app-name_version which was created after running the "glide deploy". This 2nd directory does not have the app and build subdirectories in.

If you copy the app and build subdirectories from app-name_0 to app-name_version (app-name and version being specified in the __glide.groovy) then you are a step further. This solves the "Missing web.xml (No such file or directory)" problem

In order to complete the tutorial at  http://glide-gae.appspot.com/docs/intro you may also need [this answer for an an alternative way to set your GAE upload credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465512/glide-gaelyk-groovy-error-deploying-to-google-app-engine-cant-enter-oauth2-to/21465513#21465513).